# WordPress Sanitaizing Select Optin For Custom Post Type Metabox

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Using WordPress 3.8.1, I have a Custom post Type called "Map" and it contains a Metadata which is a `Select` options element as:

```
<label for="my_meta_box_select">Countries</label>
<select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select">
<option value="asia" <?php selected( $selected, 'asia' ); ?>>Asia</option>
<option value="africa" <?php selected( $selected, 'africa' ); ?>>Africa</option>
<option value="america" <?php selected( $selected, 'america' ); ?>>America</option>
</select>

$selected = isset( $values['my_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_select'][0] ) : '';
```

so far I am using following code to save the selected option:

```
if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );
```

But from the point of Security check I am not sure that this is safe enough?! Do I have to check anything more like Sanitizing or Escaping on this kind of inputs, as well?( I already learned that we can Sanitize Text inputs but not sure about Select, or Checkbox inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're using is fine. The value that esc_attr is sanitising is a string. The fact it came from a select field and not a text input doesn't matter.

To make it even stricter you could hold the select option values in an array and then use in_array() to make sure the post value is valid.